# Using Bootstrap JS components with browserify-shim

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, browserify, commonjs, browserify-shim

I am trying to figure out how to properly use browserify-shim in conduction with the bootstrap js or any other components. I don't always want to include the whole concatenated JS file so I splitted the modules in single shims, here's an excerpt from my package.json

```
"browserify": {
  "transform": ["browserify-shim"]
},
"browser": {
  "twbs-affix": "./node_modules/bootstrap/js/affix.js",
  "twbs-alert": "./node_modules/bootstrap/js/alert.js",
  "twbs-carousel": "./node_modules/bootstrap/js/carousel.js",
  "twbs-collapse": "./node_modules/bootstrap/js/collapse.js",
  "twbs-dropdown": "./node_modules/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js",
  "twbs-modal": "./node_modules/bootstrap/js/modal.js",
  "twbs-popover": "./node_modules/bootstrap/js/popover.js",
  "twbs-scrollspy": "./node_modules/bootstrap/js/scrollspy.js",
  "twbs-tab": "./node_modules/bootstrap/js/tab.js",
  "twbs-tooltip": "./node_modules/bootstrap/js/tooltip.js",
  "twbs-transition": "./node_modules/bootstrap/js/transition.js",
  "jquery": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
},
"browserify-shim": {
  "jquery": "jQuery",
  "twbs-affix": {
    "depends": ["jquery"]
  },
  "twbs-alert": {
    "depends": ["jquery"]
  },
  "twbs-carousel": {
    "depends": ["jquery"]
  },
  "twbs-collapse": {
    "depends": ["jquery"]
  },
  "twbs-dropdown": {
    "depends": ["jquery"]
  },
  "twbs-modal": {
    "depends": ["jquery"]
  },
  "twbs-popover": {
    "depends": ["jquery"]
  },
  "twbs-scrollspy": {
    "depends": ["jquery"]
  },
  "twbs-tab": {
    "depends": ["jquery"]
  },
  "twbs-tooltip": {
    "depends": ["jquery"]
  },
  "twbs-transition": {
    "depends": ["jquery"]
  }
}
```

Now when I need the `twbs-alert` module somewhere I can include it with `require('twbs-alert')`. Is this how you would do it or doesn't it really matter to split the components because the unused components would be removed anyway during the minification process ?

**Edit**

Since [v4 of bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/js/src/alert.js) is written completely in es6 the shim approach will be obsolete since you can import the modules via the [import statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: whats the point of browserify bower components?

Comment: Bower+browserify in conduction with something like https://github.com/eugeneware/debowerify ? I'll give it a try, thanks.

Comment: Seems like there is no way of defining dependencies when you use the debowerify approach.

Comment: @webdeb usually the point is that many packages are only available on bower - bootstrap [used to be one of those](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2014/06/09/bootstrap-npm/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unused components would not be removed during the minification process, so your approach is a good one.

The best analog to your question is how people try to avoid importing unused components from Lodash/Underscore. This does not work out of the box during minification. If you're using Babel there is [a plugin](https://github.com/lodash/babel-plugin-lodash) that achieves the desired result for those libraries.

One option for you would be to write your own similar Babel plugin for Bootstrap.

Comment: I just looked at the v4 code of bootstrap and the code is written in es6 which would make the plugin obsolete when the version will be released. I think I'll  wait till version 4 will be stable and use the shim approach for a while.